How to prevent interruption of the Outlook Object Model when using _ItemAdd
I have some VBA code in ThisOutlookSession in Outlook, intended to add behaviour. For example the following:
Public WithEvents PrimaryDeletedItems as Outlook.Items

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
    Set PrimaryDeletedItems = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items
End Sub

Private Sub PrimaryDeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Item.UnRead = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

The code is intended to add simple functionality - in this case, simply mark mail items that get deleted as read, so that the deleted items folder doesn't show an 'unread item' count.
However, I noticed that this is somehow interrupting or perhaps replacing Outlook's own behaviour: if I for example accept an invitation within Outlook, Outlook normally makes the calendar item definite and moves the invitation to the deleted items folder. However, with the above code in place, the invitation is moved to the deleted items folder but the calendar item remains unchanged (still marked as "tentative", like other as-yet unanswered invitations). Something similar happens with _ItemChange; using this procedure prevents Outlook's normal behaviour, so for example a new reply will end up without the default signature for replies that is normally automatically inserted.
I do not want to modify or replace Outlook's own procedures; I only want to add additional behaviour.
This isn't mentioned in Microsoft's ItemAdd or ItemChange pages, so it's not clear whether it's expected behaviour.
I originally tried to see whether it's possible to run my code after a delay, but using Sleep doesn't appear to change the (loss of) behaviour. VBA also doesn't support coroutines or asynchronous operations, and I didn't find a way to schedule a delayed procedure like is apparently possible with Application.OnTime in Excel.

Can you reproduce the behaviour when this is the only VBA code?

Instead of On Error Resume Next try specifying If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78863595/1571407

I couldn't reproduce the behaviour after removing all other code... and now I can't reproduce the behaviour after restoring the removed code, at least for the deletion. I'll try fiddling some more with the new-reply case to see if I can find when it does and doesn't happen, that one is still preventing the addition of the signature.
